# Java Selenium - findElementById

Tags: java, selenium

I loaded `selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59`.

While trying to code, I couldn't get the method `findElementById()`. Instead, I am getting only old method `findElement()`.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

According to [docs](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/getting_started_with_webdriver/locating_elements/) you have to use this:

```java
WebElement cheese = driver.findElement(By.id("cheese"));
```

Comment: No. This is for older version i guess

Comment: What is your version an what's docs version?